# typescript preview pane in Visual Studio 2015 missing

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I recently installed Visual Studio 2015 and added in Web Essentials.  When i'm using Typescript I'm not seeing the preview pane, I had it working in Visual Studio 2013.  I've checked my Web Essential settings and I see the "Show Preview Pane" is set to True.  Is there a shortcut to bring it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a known [issue](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2015/issues/53). Hopefully VS team will add this feature in a future release.

> The TS preview pane has been removed from Web Essentials 2015 due to
>   continuously running into conflicts with the TS compiler when new
>   versions come out. The TS team are aware of it and I hope they will
>   add the feature into the TS tooling in the future. It is possible that
>   this feature will be included in the brand new Web Compiler extensions
>   (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b329021-cd7a-4a01-86fc-714c2d05bb6c)
>   when preview panes have been implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can hit the `Solution Explorer->Show All Files` button to find your `.js` file and then hit **Alt + W, V** or go to Visual Studio menu `Windows->New Vertical Tab Group`:
[image: Print Screen]

To get a vertical split window and open the `.js` file right next to your `.ts` file.